# Make Mat-Raised-Button HTML link to PDF (Angular 6 + Material)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

Good afternoon,

I have two closely related questions:
1. When I click the following code:

HTML

```
<a mat-raised-button 
class="sample-button" 
color="primary" 
href="{{card.ButtonURL}}"
>{{card.Label}}</a>
```

Object Referenced (typescript):

```
  {
    Name:'Test PDF', cols: 1, rows: 1,
    Label: 'Test PDF',
    ButtonURL: '../pdfs/test.pdf',
    imageURL: 'https://png.icons8.com/material/480/00457C/upload-link-document.png',
    imageDesc: 'Test Description',
    },
```

Why does  `<a mat-raised-button href="../pdfs/test.pdf"></a>`change the URL (see image 4) instead of opening the test.pdf in a new window?

2. If I have a survey, and would like to link to a file for download from my web server, does that need to be configured within the angular web application or can i just point to the file path on the server?

Thank you for your help, i am a novice.

Images:

[Folder Structure Root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoNwH.png)

[Folder Structure /src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2vxm.png)

[Screenshot of Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn43r.png)

[Screenshot of Application after Test Link is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEPRT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to add target to `<a>` to open this in new tab
example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{card.ButtonURL}}">{{card.Label}}</a>
```

Secondly you have to be sure that the url is valid, I mean there is really pdf in this location. I suggest you also to put your PDF file in assets folder - default for angular to store local files

Comment: I believe my problem was that I tried to place target="" after href=""
I was using the <a></a> tag. I also switched to using the assets folder and all appears to be working correctly. Thank you for your help

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: I also have found that this will ONLY work if the pdf is in the assets folder. I tried multiple ways to point to it in a different folder and it never worked, but as soon as i pointed to it in the assets folder, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @MrShantastic Well, this couldn't work when the file was in different place to /assets. That's because the assets folder is configured to serve static files, and the scripts have access to it. If you put the file in different place then served app doesn't have the files locally.